# CLLocationManager Delegate method didUpdateToLocation not called on user's device

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, location, cllocationmanager

My app requires location data to run. I makes sure user has to accept location services for my app before logging in. If user declines, it will prevent user log in until user grants the app permission to use location services.

Everything is working well except for 1 test user's device. The device is not getting the location data at all even if the user granted the app location services permission. There is no GPS icon appears. Google map is working fine for the user's device. I'm really not sure what is going on here. It looks like `didUpdateToLocation` is not called on this user's device at all. What could be causing this issue?

Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    [self getCurrentLocation];
    ...
}

- (void)getCurrentLocation {
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100; // meters
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        [self setLatitude:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]];
        [self setLongitude:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]];
        if (loginController) {
            [loginController validateSession];
            loginController = nil;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if you are trying in device then please remove the locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;  because didupdate location method call after every 100 meter your phone walk for testing u can remove it

Answer (score 1):

Please Check the below commends. Some times this same issue Happened for me.

1. Uninstall completely and Re Install and check Application again.
2. Reset Network Settings in iPhone Settings.
3. Delete previous installed application and reinstall again.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using

```
- (void)startUpdatingLocation;
```

But you use

```
- (void)startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges;
```

Since you set up all the filter you probably want to use the first (`startUpdatingLocation`).

As to why this didn't work one a single user's device:startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges does not use GPS to triangulate the position of the user and therefore comparing it with google maps does not help you.

For more information on both methods investigate further in Apple's documentation:
[Apple Doku](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation)

Comment: That is not true. It works for every other users. The GPS icons comes up on every other devices except this one user. startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges just updates less often and the delivery of location events come slower than startUpdatingLocation

Comment: these lines: locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100; // meters    are completely disregarded if you use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. Thats what I wanted to point out. And actually YES, startMonitoringForSig.. does not need GPS, but it uses it some times. But the other way around it NEEDS wifi or celluar!